# Handle groups of messages in parallel but each message in a group consecutive

Tags: c#, azure-storage-queues, asp.net5

I have a queue on which messages from several devices come in. I want to handle the messages belonging to the different devices in parallel but the messages for a specific device must be handled consecutive.

Example:
Lets say that I have 3 devices: A, B and C and they are all sending messages to the same queue.
On the other side of the queue I have some worker process that reads the messages and need to do some work based on them.

```
Queue
Message A1
Message B1
Message A2
Message C1
Message B2
Message A3
Message B3
Message C2
Message C3
```

The worker process can handle the messages from A, B and C in parallel but the order of the messages for the specific devices must be handled consecutive: after A1, A2 can be picked up and then A3.

I have it already working with every message handled consecutive but this does not perform well when there are a lot of devices sending messages.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Comment: Create a queue per device?

Comment: It's possible you may need something like service bus instead of storage queues. Service bus is quicker, works by subscription instead of polling and I think partitions would help in this scenario.

Comment: Just to update, I think sessions in service bus is what you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions for grouping related messages so you can have 1 worker per session preserving FIFO

Comment: I finally got time to work on this again. What I did was creating a receiver and sender queue per device. The managing is done by sending events via the service bus.

Comment: In the past I used the Service Bus also for the device communication, but I found it not reliable enough (we use the standard tier). Sometimes there were long delays.